# Load DLL Assemblies from file in C# to custom AppDomain

Tags: c#, reflection, dll, assemblies

I tryed next code:

```
AppDomain ad = AppDomain.CreateDomain("Test");      
_Assembly = parDomain.Load(AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(@"C:\SomeDLLPath\PhysicsTest.dll"));
// Some work with assembly
AppDomain.Unload(ad);
```

It raise `FileNotFoundException that cannot load file or assembly "TestClass, Version=1.0.0.0, ..."`

If I Load Assembly to this domain all OK:

```
_Assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(@"C:\SomeDLLPath\PhysicsTest.dll");
```

But i need to unload this too.

I saw many threads about it but can't understand them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173101%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

> Blockquote
>
> There is no way to unload an individual assembly without unloading all of the application domains that contain it. Even if the assembly goes out of scope, the actual assembly file will remain loaded until all application domains that contain it are unloaded.

Here is how to unload a AppDomain [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5b8a8f9.aspx#Y0)

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

class AppDomain2
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Creating new AppDomain.");
        AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("MyDomain", null);

        Console.WriteLine("Host domain: " + AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName);
        Console.WriteLine("child domain: " + domain.FriendlyName);
        AppDomain.Unload(domain);
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Host domain: " + AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName);
            // The following statement creates an exception because the domain no longer exists.
            Console.WriteLine("child domain: " + domain.FriendlyName);
        }
        catch (AppDomainUnloadedException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.GetType().FullName);
            Console.WriteLine("The appdomain MyDomain does not exist.");
        }
    }
}
```